# wrap each char in except tags with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to wrap each text character inside a

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

with a span tag.
No problem there, it's just that I also need to keep nested tags unmodified.

So if the string inside the DIV is:

```
"Some random text, <b>but</b> wait - there's <a href="http://w3.org">tags</a> inside!"
```

It should output this for the "but" part

```
<b><span>b</b><span>u</span><span>t</span></b>
```

Leaving the < b> and < a> tags alone, but wrapping all other chars in span. I checked text() but that doesn't seem to have a way of preserving tags or "saving back", only extracting the text and permanently removing the < b> and < a>

Maybe some jQuery guru out there knows how to do this?

Comment: jQuery doesn't make use of textnodes. It's better for you to use javascript and don't try it with jQuery

Comment: @rsplak, so how come my solution with jQuery works just fine? ;) There's no need to work with the textnodes themselves. Just check if it's a textnode or not, then you can manipulate it with jQuery.

Comment: @marcus ekwall: nice, +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using the following code:

```
$("div").children().andSelf().contents().each(function(){
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.replaceWith($this.text().replace(/(\w)/g, "<span>$&</span>"));
    }
});
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/uYyJE/).

Comment: wow, thanks! thats perfect for my needs, i just didn't know about the nodeType thing until now - tried finding something like that before i posted.

Comment: i haven't updated my jsfiddle example with this code yet, but to see what i'm trying to accomplish with this - check out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755303/quest-for-the-ultimate-inline-wysiwyg-using-jquery

Comment: It doesn't work for characters like é and , etc. How does the regex look for that?

Comment: @clankill3er JavaScript's unicode support is abysmal. I will refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052825/regular-expression-for-all-printable-characters-in-javascript) for that.

Comment: This wont work if your <strong> is nested in a <span> or so.  See http://jsfiddle.net/xhL9889n/ -- How would you go about improving this to work on nested elements?