# set id for each one with jquery

Tags: jquery

I saw this:

```
$("div").children().andSelf().contents().each(function(){
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.replaceWith($this.text().replace(/(\w)/g, "<span>$&</span>"));
    }
});
```

here:
[wrap each char in except tags with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754450/wrap-each-char-in-except-tags-with-jquery)

Now i try to give each span a id, but they end up all having the same id.
The index that get's logged to the console however are different.

```
$("#content").children().andSelf().contents().each(function(index){
    console.log(index);
        if (this.nodeType == 3) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.replaceWith($this.text().replace(/(\w)/g, "<span id="+index+">$&</span>"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, you are replacing each character on one text node with the same `"<span id="+index+">$&</span>"` string. The `index` for each text node will be different though.

Comment: In your log, are you seeing what is expected? have you tried doing console.log(this.noteType), or console.log($this)? Add more traces, it should help with the debugging process. [Side note: to change the id of an element, you can just do $this.prop("id",index)]

Comment: I tested with "logo" so it logged 1, 2, 3, 4 but it didn't occur to me that that where the elements. Anyway how can i solve this? Also i don't understand the values it logs,  the div #content only contains  1 paragraph.

Comment: console.log(this.noteType) logs 3. console.log($this) logs strange stuff like ["      ] "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1234725/520779) might be of use to you.

If you want each letter in a span, an an unique id for each one, here's how it could be done:

```
$("#content").children().andSelf().contents().each(function(index){
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.replaceWith($this.text().replace(/\w/g, function(text,index2) {
            return "<span id="+index+""+index2+">" + text + "</span>";
        }));
    }
});
```

Obs.: I'm not sure every browser support this form of `Regex.replace`. Tested with FF3.6 and Chrome.

Clarifying a bit: This form is new to me too, just learned today, but couldn't find relevant documentation online. It appears that, for a regex **without** capturing groups, the first argument is the matched text and the second it's index in the original string. Otherwise, the second argument becomes the first captured group, and I assume the 3rd is the 2nd c.g. and so on... If anyone know where to find more info, I'm interested in it too.