# JavaScript: For-Loop not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I got the following code (I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754450/wrap-each-char-in-except-tags-with-jquery) ):

```
$( "p" ).children().andSelf().contents().each( function () {
  if ( this.nodeType == 3 ) {
    var $this = $( this );
    var regEx = /(\w)/g;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      $this.replaceWith( $this.text().replace( regEx, "<span class='numbers"+ i +"'>$&</span>" ));
     }
   }
});
```

It's part of a function that is working fine. Only when I add that for-Loop it fails.

The Problem: When I `console.log(i)` it increments as expected. When I `alert(i)`, it alerts 0-4 for six times. Also, `i` isn't added to the `numberX` class. Looking at the DOM, `i` is always zero. What's wrong with the loop?

Comment: Will need to see the rest of the code.

Comment: I think its all about closure ...

Comment: I think you mistyped `$this`, it should be `$(this)`?

Comment: What is `regEx`?  What is `$this`?

Comment: Are you embedding your `for` loop in another so it ran 6 times?

Comment: Why are you replacing (the same) `$this` 6 times?

Comment: Would [`.wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) (or [`.wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)) work for you?

Comment: Please note: I edited the question with the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for` loop when `i==0`, `this` in the DOM has been replaced by your new `<span>` element, but in JavaScript context, `this` still refers to your original element. That's why further replacement won't work and the class is stuck at `0`.

Let's say for example your original element is a `<div>`:

```
i     | this  | The same place in DOM
======|=======|======================================
-     | <div> | <div>
0     | <div> | replaced by <span class="number0">
1...5 | <div> | <span class="number0"> (not affected)
```

Because after `i==0`, this is already off the DOM. So further replacement don't work.

A way to correct your code will be:

```
$("div").children().andSelf().contents().each(function(index,item){
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        var $this = $(item);
        var arr=$this.text().match(/(\w)/g);
        arr.forEach(function(item,i,a){a[i]=item.replace(/(.*)/, "<span class='number"+i+"'>$&</span>");});
        $this.replaceWith(arr.join(""));
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KVm9C/

Comment: Alright, thank you. I think I've understood what the problem is. So do you know any way to "re-set" it?