# Regular expression for all printable characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Looking for a regular expression for that validates all printable characters. The regex needs to be used in JavaScript only. I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247762/regex-for-all-printable-characters) post but it mostly talks about .net, Java and C but not JavaScript.

You have to allow only these printable characters :

> a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and the thirty-two symbols: !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[] ^_`{|}~ and space

Need a JavaScript regex to validate the input characters is one of the above and discard the rest.

Comment: All? Are you sure? Are you aware of just how many unicode characters there are?

Comment: Unfortunately javascript does not support unicode character classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode

Comment: Unicode UTF-16 has some 2^16 I guess.

Comment: @AurA: Not even close. You definitely need to read Joel's [Unicode article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) before venturing any further into this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to match all printable characters in the UTF-8 set (as indicated by your comment on Aug 21), you're going to have a hard time doing this yourself. JavaScript's native regexes have abysmal Unicode support. But you can use [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) with the regex `^\P{C}*$`.

If you only want to match those few ASCII letters you mentioned in the edit to your post from Aug 22, then the regex is trivial:

```
/^[a-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@\[\] ^_`{|}~-]*$/i
```

Comment: that I guess is a good solution but suppose I want printable characters for UTF-8 only, can you get me a regular expression without using any third party JavaScript library.

Comment: @AurA: XRegExp compiles down to native JavaScript.

Comment: I already know that but I have that restriction here... that I cannot use a third party library. That is why i am asking for UTF-8 only, that would reduce that number of characters drastically and can be handled with regex.

Comment: UTF-8 has *EXACTLY* the same number of characters as UTF-16 and UTF-32. UTF-8 is just an encoding - it has ALL of unicode - the entire thing. Did you mean ASCII?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8  Out of these given characters I want to check if the entered string has any unprintable character or on keypress I want to check if entered character is printable.

Answer (score 13):

For non-unicode use regex pattern `^[^\x00-\x1F\x80-\x9F]+$`

---

If you want to work with unicode, first read [Javascript + Unicode regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode).

I would suggest then to use regex pattern `^[^\p{Cc}\p{Cf}\p{Zl}\p{Zp}]*$`

- `\p{Cc}` or `\p{Control}`: an ASCII 0x00..0x1F or Latin-1 0x80..0x9F control character.
- `\p{Cf}` or `\p{Format}`: invisible formatting indicator.
- `\p{Zl}` or `\p{Line_Separator}`: line separator character U+2028.
- `\p{Zp}` or `\p{Paragraph_Separator}`: paragraph separator character U+2029.

For more information see http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: You can use https://github.com/mathiasbynens/regexpu-core to transpile it to ES5.

Answer (score 13):

To validate a string only consists of printable *ASCII* characters, use a simple regex like

```
/^[ -~]+$/
```

It matches

- `^` - the start of string anchor
- `[ -~]+` - one or more (due to `+` quantifier) characters that are within a range from space till a tilde in the ASCII table:

[image]
 - `$` - end of string anchor

For Unicode printable chars, use `\PC` Unicode category (matching any char but a control char) from [`XRegExp`](http://xregexp.com/), as has already been mentioned:

```
^\PC+$
```

See regex demos:

```js
// ASCII only
var ascii_print_rx = /^[ -~]+$/;
console.log(ascii_print_rx.test("It's all right.")); // true
console.log(ascii_print_rx.test('\f ')); // false, \f is an ASCII form feed char
console.log(ascii_print_rx.test("demásiado tarde")); // false, no Unicode printable char support
// Unicode support
console.log(XRegExp.test('demásiado tarde', XRegExp("^\\PC+$"))); // true
console.log(XRegExp.test('‌ ', XRegExp("^\\PC+$"))); // false, \u200C is a Unicode zero-width joiner
console.log(XRegExp.test('\f ', XRegExp("^\\PC+$"))); // false, \f is an ASCII form feed char
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.1.1/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The first option is ingenious (unless we need Unicode).

Answer (score 11):

Looks like JavaScript has changed to some degree since this question was posted?

I'm using this one:

```
var regex = /^[\u0020-\u007e\u00a0-\u00ff]*$/;
console.log( regex.test("!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[] ^_`{|}~")); //should output "true" 
console.log( regex.test("Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn")); //should output "true"
console.log( regex.test("☃")); //should output "false"
```

Comment: I think it should be `\x20-\x7e` `\x80-\xff`

Answer (score 9):

### TLDR Answer

Use `string1.match(/[\p{Cc}\p{Cn}\p{Cs}]+/gu)` as a conditional, with true meaning that `string1` *contains any unprintable characters.*

Or, if you want the logical equivalent, `string1.match(/^[\P{Cc}\P{Cn}\P{Cs}]+$/gu)` as a conditional will return true if `string1` *only contains printable characters.*

### TLDR Explanation

- `\P{Cc}` : *Do not* match control characters.
- `\P{Cn}` : *Do not* match unassigned characters.
- `\P{Cs}` : *Do not* match UTF-8-invalid characters.
- `+` : Make sure that something is found, i.e., this will also mean that `""`, the blank string, will not be considered printable.
- `/g` : Greedy match, exhaustively/greedily search the string for the character sets indicated.
- `/u` : The unicode regex operator for matching on unicode character points. (Source: [MDN Web Docs: Regular Expressions; Unicode Property Escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes).)

### Demo

```js
var string1 = 'This string has unprintable characters \u0001';

if(string1.match(/[\p{Cc}\p{Cn}\p{Cs}]+/gu)) {
  console.log("Unprintable string: " + string1);
}
var string2 = 'This string has only printable characters.';

if(string2.match(/^[\P{Cc}\P{Cn}\P{Cs}]+$/gu)) {
  console.log("Printable string: " + string2);
}
```

### Possible Alternatives

- `\P{C}` : Match only visible characters.  Do not match any invisible characters.
- `\P{Cc}` : Match only non-control characters.  Do not match any control characters.
- `\P{Cc}\P{Cn}` : Match only non-control characters that have been assigned.  Do not match any control or unassigned characters.
- `\P{Cc}\P{Cn}\P{Cs}` :  Match only non-control characters that have been assigned and are UTF-8 valid.  Do not match any control, unassigned, or UTF-8-invalid characters.
- `\P{Cc}\P{Cn}\P{Cs}\P{Cf}` :  Match only non-control, non-formatting characters that have been assigned and are UTF-8 valid.  Do not match any control, unassigned, formatting, or UTF-8-invalid characters.

### Source and Explanation

Take a look at the [Unicode Character Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) available that can be used to test within a regex.  You should be able to use these regexes in [Microsoft .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions), [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes), [Python](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), [Java](https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode), [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/parle.regex.unicodecharclass.php), [Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html), [Perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlrecharclass), [Golang](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/), and even [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-regular-expressions-in-functions/regular-expression-syntax.html).  Knowing Unicode character classes is *very transferable knowledge*, so I recommend using it!

This regex will match anything visible, given in both its short-hand and long-hand form...

```
\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{P}\p{S}\p{Z}
\p{Letter}\p{Mark}\p{Number}\p{Punctuation}\p{Symbol}\p{Separator}
```

`\p` indicates that it's something we want to match, but we also have the option to use `\P` (capitalized) [to indicate something that *does not match.*](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-regular-expressions-in-functions/regular-expression-syntax.html)  So, that means we can use the `\p{C}` class, used for "invisible control characters and unused code points." (Source: [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop).)  A simpler regex then would be `\P{C}`, but this might be too restrictive in deleting invisible formatting.  You may want to look closely and see what's best, but one of the alternatives should fit your needs.

#### All Matchable Unicode Character Sets

If you want to know any other character sets available, check out [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)...

- **`\p{L}`** or **`\p{Letter}`**: any kind of letter from any language.

  - `\p{Ll}` or `\p{Lowercase_Letter}`: a lowercase letter that has an uppercase variant.
  - `\p{Lu}` or `\p{Uppercase_Letter}`: an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant.
  - `\p{Lt}` or `\p{Titlecase_Letter}`: a letter that appears at the start of a word when only the first letter of the word is capitalized.
  - `\p{L&}` or `\p{Cased_Letter}`: a letter that exists in lowercase and uppercase variants (combination of Ll, Lu and Lt).
  - `\p{Lm}` or `\p{Modifier_Letter}`: a special character that is used like a letter.
  - `\p{Lo}` or `\p{Other_Letter}`: a letter or ideograph that does not have lowercase and uppercase
- **`\p{M}`** or **`\p{Mark}`**: a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.).

  - `\p{Mn}` or `\p{Non_Spacing_Mark}`: a character intended to be combined with another
    character without taking up extra space (e.g. accents, umlauts, etc.).
  - `\p{Mc}` or `\p{Spacing_Combining_Mark}`: a character intended to be combined with another character that takes up extra space (vowel signs in many Eastern languages).
  - `\p{Me}` or `\p{Enclosing_Mark}`: a character that encloses the character it is combined with (circle, square, keycap, etc.).
- **`\p{Z}`** or **`\p{Separator}`**: any kind of whitespace or invisible separator.

  - `\p{Zs}` or `\p{Space_Separator}`: a whitespace character that is invisible, but does take up space.
  - `\p{Zl}` or `\p{Line_Separator}`: line separator character U+2028.
  - `\p{Zp}` or `\p{Paragraph_Separator}`: paragraph separator character U+2029.
- **`\p{S}`** or **`\p{Symbol}`**: math symbols, currency signs, dingbats, box-drawing characters, etc.

  - `\p{Sm}` or `\p{Math_Symbol}`: any mathematical symbol.
  - `\p{Sc}` or `\p{Currency_Symbol}`: any currency sign.
  - `\p{Sk}` or `\p{Modifier_Symbol}`: a combining character (mark) as a full character on its own.
  - `\p{So}` or `\p{Other_Symbol}`: various symbols that are not math symbols, currency signs, or combining characters.
- **`\p{N}`** or **`\p{Number}`**: any kind of numeric character in any script.

  - `\p{Nd}` or `\p{Decimal_Digit_Number}`: a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts.
  - `\p{Nl}` or `\p{Letter_Number}`: a number that looks like a letter, such as a Roman numeral.
  - `\p{No}` or `\p{Other_Number}`: a superscript or subscript digit, or a number that is not a digit 0–9 (excluding numbers from ideographic scripts).
- **`\p{P}`** or **`\p{Punctuation}`**: any kind of punctuation character.

  - `\p{Pd}` or `\p{Dash_Punctuation}`: any kind of hyphen or dash.
  - `\p{Ps}` or `\p{Open_Punctuation}`: any kind of opening bracket.
  - `\p{Pe}` or `\p{Close_Punctuation}`: any kind of closing bracket.
  - `\p{Pi}` or `\p{Initial_Punctuation}`: any kind of opening quote.
  - `\p{Pf}` or `\p{Final_Punctuation}`: any kind of closing quote.
  - `\p{Pc}` or `\p{Connector_Punctuation}`: a punctuation character such as an underscore that connects words.
  - `\p{Po}` or `\p{Other_Punctuation}`: any kind of punctuation character that is not a dash, bracket, quote or connector.
- **`\p{C}`** or **`\p{Other}`**: invisible control characters and unused code points.

  - `\p{Cc}` or `\p{Control}`: an ASCII or Latin-1 control character: 0x00–0x1F and 0x7F–0x9F.
  - `\p{Cf}` or `\p{Format}`: invisible formatting indicator.
  - `\p{Co}` or `\p{Private_Use}`: any code point reserved for private use.
  - `\p{Cs}` or `\p{Surrogate}`: one half of a surrogate pair in UTF-16 encoding.
  - `\p{Cn}` or `\p{Unassigned}`: any code point to which no character has been assigned.