# javascript validate SSID and WPA/WPA2

Tags: javascript, regex, ssid, wpa

I am trying to get 2 functions to validate an SSID and WPA2 passcode.

```
function isValidSSID(ssid) {
    return (regex)
}
```

and

```
function isValidWPA(passcode) {
    return (regex)
}
```

I was hoping to find a regex for each...

I was looking for what are valid characters for each:

> The SSID can consist of up to 32 alphanumeric, case-sensitive, characters.
>   The first character cannot be the !, #, or ; character.
>   The +, ], /, ", TAB, and trailing spaces are invalid characters for SSIDs.

WPA:
https://superuser.com/questions/223513/what-are-the-technical-requirements-for-a-wpa-psk-passphrase

Thanks,
Don

Update:

the SSID function that worked for me:

```
function isValidSSID(str) { return /^[!#;].|[+\[\]/"\t\s].*$/.test(str); }
```

I used the site https://regex101.com/r/ddZ9zc/2/

the WPA function that worked for me:

```
 function isValidWPA(str) { return /^[\u0020-\u007e\u00a0-\u00ff]*$/.test(str); }
```

[Regular expression for all printable characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052825/regular-expression-for-all-printable-characters-in-javascript)

I did the length check elsewhere in javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide examples of input and expected output (pass/fail) and give it a try yourself.  People are here to help you learn, not do your work.  Unless you want to pay hourly.

Comment: Is there a question in here that I'm missing?

Comment: figured it out for my self...

Comment: @ Don E.: can you share? : )

Comment: https://github.com/cyoung/stratux/blob/ec997fbf98a27ef53002dc4207ae7d22bbb409a6/web/plates/js/settings.js#L310

Answer (score 5):

I use this regex to match SSID:

```
^[^!#;+\]\/"\t][^+\]\/"\t]{0,30}[^ !#;+\]\/"\t]$|^[^ !#;+\]\/"\t]$
```

Answer (score 5):

I used andrey's answer to come up with this:

```
^[^!#;+\]\/"\t][^+\]\/"\t]{0,30}[^ +\]\/"\t]$|^[^ !#;+\]\/"\t]$[ \t]+$
```

The SSID can consist of up to 32 alphanumeric, case-sensitive, characters. The first character cannot be the !, #, or ; character. The +, ], /, ", TAB, and trailing spaces are invalid characters for SSIDs.

With the regex andrey provided you could not use !, # or ; in the string at all however the text above specifies that they can't be used only at the start of the string.

Comment: Can you give a source why the first character cannot be one of the ones you stated? Other than a website from Cisco for their IOS products, I assume that there are simply no restrictions for SSIDs, except that it's not longer than 32 octets. Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5017144/176248

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer, but also a question - does anyone have experience with foreign language or graphics in an SSID?
I found the following:

[Using Emoji in SSID](https://www.howtogeek.com/817661/can-you-use-emoji-in-wi-fi-network-names/)
But if you dig into the governing standards for Wi-Fi, the 802.11 standards maintained by the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (IEEE), you find something surprising: **The only constraint for setting an SSID for a wireless network is that it must be between 1 and 32 octets long, an octet being 8 bits of data.**

As of Unicode 14.0, there are 144,697 characters, including characters for hundreds of languages and thousands of emoji symbols. Emoji symbols, interestingly enough, are 2 octets not a single octet like the character A or the number 2. [So too foreign alphabets - each letter take 2 octets.]

So every emoji in your SSID counts as two regular plaintext characters—you can have a 16 emoji SSID, a 30 plaintext character SSID with a single emoji, or any combination between the two that adds up to 32 total octets.

Answer (score 0):

For SSID I would use this regex (excluding the case of zero-length):

```
/^[^!#;+\]/"\t][^+\]/"\t]{0,31}$/
```

For WPA passphrase (8 to 63 printable ASCII characters, with encoding ranging from 32 to 126):

```
/^[\u0020-\u007e]{8,63}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight improvement on Sparers excellent version,   I noticed while making something for a freeradius service, it can match over newlines when it is inserted into grouping...   This version, although with other drawbacks, cannot:

```
([^!#;+\]\/"\t\n][^+\]\/"\t\n]{0,30}[^ +\]\/"\t\n]|^[^ !#;+\]\/"\t\n][ \t]+)$
```